# Align all labels height, across one row, that are above each input field

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, css-grid

As you can see from the picture label 2 extends across two lines since it's longer. How can I align the rest of the labels so that the input boxes all align in one row horizontally?

[image: Picture of the issue]

Comment: Please include your HTML, nobody can help you with a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a fixed Height to your labels (bigger than two row of text). Or maybe trying to vertical-align your input to bottom